# How do I stop Eclipse's format from messing up my code?

Tags: eclipse

For some reason Eclipse has started messing up my code when I `CTRL + SHIFT + F` to format.  Any line longer than 80 characters is getting wrapped, and lines with comments at the end really get messed up.

Before `CTRL + SHIFT + F`:

```
projectile.setPosition((CAMERA_WIDTH / 2) - (projectile.getWidth() / 2), 800);//projectile center is set to middle of screen at bottom
```

After `CTRL + SHIFT + F`:

```
    projectile.setPosition(
            (CAMERA_WIDTH / 2) - (projectile.getWidth() / 2), 800);// projectile
                                                                    // center
                                                                    // is
                                                                    // set
                                                                    // to
                                                                    // middle
                                                                    // of
                                                                    // screen
                                                                    // at
                                                                    // bottom
```

In `Window > Preferences > General > Editors > Text Editors` my `Print margin column` is set to 150 and that is the only preference I have changed.  Even when I restore defaults Eclipse still messes up my code.

How do I change this feature?

Comment: Is this a real question?  Isn't the only valid answer - "Because it does!"?

Comment: actually I quite like this setting as it increases readability quite a lot. But I guess it's personal taste.

Comment: @Stephen C If you want to get technical it was not a real question, I thought the question was implied.  I added a question to the end for you.

Comment: as you originally wrote the question, it looked like it was just a rant about Eclipse's formatter.  I sympathize ... but that would not be a valid SO question.  I have edited the question title to make it clear that this is a real question, not just a rant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just adjust the formatter settings to your personal preferences and gusto and you are set. There are LOTS of options and line wrap and line width are some of them

Comment: Thanks, in Netbeans where I set the print margin is where the code wraps at. Didn't realize I had to change 2 setting to get the same effect in Eclipse.  Thx.

Comment: @typoknig, you should add an answer with the exact setting you changed and accept it.

Answer (score 2):

The preference you want is under  `Window > Preferences > Java > Code Style > Formatter`.   Edit the profile, go to the `Line Wrapping` tab, and set the `Maximum line width`.